# Partitioning a graph in two set

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

Could someone please give me an idea on how to partition a graph into 2 set (set A and set B), such that the number of edges between the two set of nodes (A and B) is almost maximum? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to calculate the [maximum cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cut).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there any algorithm to solve this. I know that the optimal solution is np-hard. I just need at least half the optimal solution.

Comment: Have you checked the "Approximation algorithms" part? There are some nice ideas there..... "the cut includes at least |E|/2 edges."